# Cannot Expand SQL database to view tables

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms

For some reason I cannot expand one of my SQL databases to view tables using SSMS but I can expand it if I make a database connection to it using visual studio 10.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how could I fix it?

Comment: Are you connecting with the same user?

Comment: Yeah the database is local and SSMS and VS10 are both installed on the same computer.

Comment: But are you logging in to the database with the same user in SSMS and in VS10?

Comment: I used "Windows Authentication" for both cases so it should be the same user.

Comment: I'm just guessing here. Are you running VS in elevated mode (i.e. can you see "Administrator" in the window title)?

Comment: Nope. However, looking at the SSMS logs does suggest that I'm getting a OS error 32(process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process) for the specific database (.mdf and .ldf files). But i've tried closing down both VS10 and SSMS and the problem still persists. I will try to restart my computer in a bit after a download finishes.